# Create schema-free (document-oriented) table in MySQL

Tags: mysql, database-design, nosql, rdbms, object-oriented-database

We are working on a LAMP-based software with customer data as a central unit. 
The table with the customer data is supplied by various sources via the import interface. 
The problem is, the table must not have a fixed schema. 
It may be that row X has five columns and row Y has twenty columns.

Our previous solution was as follow:

```
CREATE TABLE `customers` (
  `id` int (10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `branch_id` int (10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `type` tinyint (1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `visible` tinyint (1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` tinyint (1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `2` varchar (255) NOT NULL,
  `3` varchar (255) NOT NULL,
  `4` varchar (255) NOT NULL,
  `5` varchar (255) NOT NULL,
  `6` varchar (255) NOT NULL,
  `7` varchar (255) NOT NULL,
  `8` varchar (255) NOT NULL,
  `9` varchar (255) NOT NULL,
  `10` varchar (255) NOT NULL,
  `11` varchar (255) NOT NULL,
  `12` varchar (255) NOT NULL,
  `13` varchar (255) NOT NULL,
  `14` varchar (255) NOT NULL,
  `15` varchar (255) NOT NULL,
  `17` varchar (255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `branch_id` (`branch_id`)
  FULLTEXT KEY `search` (`2`, `3`, `4`, `5`, `6`, `7`, `8`, `9`, `10`, `11`, `12`, `13`, `14`, `15`)
) ENGINE = MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8;
```

This table had a large overhead because we did not know what kind of data will be stored in the table, so we had to create only varchar(255) columns. Not seen here is a second table in which we have stored the names of the columns. This table looks something like this:

```
id   col   name
====================
1    2     firstname
2    8     zip
```

As you can see, we have started with a table that contained only the basic columns. Then we checked each time a import or update was done if new columns are added or if columns are no longer needed. If this were the case, we have deleted the corresponding column or added new ones. In addition, we always had to adjust the additional table.

This solution was a compromise for us in speed, simplicity and logic.
In our opinion the most obvious solution would be the use of a document-oriented DBMS like MongoDB.

Unfortunately, we are forced to work exclusively with MySQL.
Is there a solution to create a schema-free table in MySQL?
Or are there other approaches which would be more useful?

Comment: why don't you just use one column and store everything in xml? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/xml-functions.html

Comment: Because we must have the ability to perform joins on the attributes. As far as I know, that is not possible with XML data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should explore the [EAV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model) pattern. If you are using PHP, then there are some toolkits that could make your coding easier:

- http://code.google.com/p/zend-framework-eav/
- http://eavframework.svn.sourceforge.net/

Comment: We consider this solution now. Unfortunately, the software is built on a framework developed by us, so we do not want to integrate frameworks and classes from other sources. But it seems possible with this solution to perform complex joins as before, even if it isn't going to be that simple.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this would work for you and I'm just learning and exploring doing this myself so I welcome any corrections from the community:

Given that I would look at combining some "schema-free" tables at this point
That is

```
    CREATE TABLE `customers` (
      `id` int (10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
      `branch_id` int (10) unsigned NOT NULL,
      `type` tinyint (1) DEFAULT NULL,
      `visible` tinyint (1) DEFAULT NULL,
      `status` tinyint (1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
       PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
      KEY `branch_id` (`branch_id`)
      FULLTEXT KEY `search` (`2`, `3`, `4`, `5`, `6`, `7`, `8`, `9`, `10`, `11`, `12`, `13`, `14`, `15`)
    ) ENGINE = MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8;

    CREATE TABLE cust_info (
    id int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
    custid int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
    name varchar(32) NOT NULL,
    value varchar(255),
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    KEY `custid` (`custid`)
    ) ENGINE = MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8;
```

Now just store the "extra" information in the cust_info table assigning it to the proper custid.   If you are expecting your tables to get very large then look up schema-free in mysql (google it), and you can find some good articles on how to implement this properly (instead of my hack above).  The articles talk about building your Index tables so you can perform index maintenance on the database without bringing mysql to a very slow response state.